# How to check for DLL/SO before calling JNA Native.loadLibrary to avoid UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, ffmpeg, jna

I'm loading a native library (ffmpeg) using JNA but I need to check if the DLL/SO file exists before actually calling Native.loadLibrary().  FFMPEG may not always be installed in the system (it's a seperate download).

Native.loadLibrary() throws an ERROR which you can not trap with a try {} catch {}.

How do I check if the library (DLL or SO) exists before actually calling loadLibrary()?
Would I have to just parse the PATH environment variable and check myself?  I would have to check against Windows and Linux and ensure the correct 32/64bit .dll or .so is installed???

I wish loadLibrary just returned a null pointer or threw an exception, not an error (bad design).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the simple soln.

You CAN catch on Error.  I thought you couldn't.
I always used try {} catch (Exception e) {} to catch all exceptions but that doesn't catch Errors.
I need to use try {} catch (Error e) {} or catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ule) {} instead.

Learn something new everyday.

Comment: If you're bent on catching everything you can just catch (Throwable t)

Comment: Ya, that's what I've been doing lately.  Exception and Error are derived from Throwable.